Double integral of $xe^{-(x^2+y^2)}$
I have some troubles with the following double integral where D is $|x|\leq 1, |y|\leq 1$
$$
\iint_{D} xe^{-(x^2+y^2)} \,dx\,dy
$$
I transform it to polar coordinates where $\theta~is [0,\pi /2]:$
$$
\iint_{E} (r \cos \theta)e^{-r^2}r \,dr \,d\theta = \int_{0}^{\pi/2}\cos \theta \,d\theta \int_{0}^{1}r^2e^{-r^2}\,dr=\sin \frac{\pi}{2} \int_{0}^{1}r^2e^{-r^2}\,dr
$$
and perform a U-substitution with $u=r^2$ ending up with the following expression
$$
\int_0^1 \frac{\sqrt{u}e^{-u}}{2}\,du
$$
which I cannot integrate. I have tried integration by parts without any success. The solution says the answer is $0$.
Any suggestion is highly appreciated. Thanks.
Sincerely,
TS

It is obviously $0$: The integrand is an odd function. (Your limits are not correct).

$D$ is a square and you are integrating over a  quarter of a circle.

The second comment is right. The proper method for a square region has been answered.

why did you write $\sin (\pi/2)$ instead of $1$?

@SineoftheTime because it was the sine of the time

Thanks for pointing this out, but I'm still not able to solve it ... I rewrite it as
$$
\int_0^1 xe^{-x^2}dx \int_0^1 e^{-y^2}dy = \int_0^1 xe^{-x^2}dx (- \frac{1}{2e})
$$
and perform a substituton as
$$

\frac{1}{2e} \int_0^1 \frac{e^{-t}}{2} dt = - \frac{1}{4e}(- \frac{1}{e}+1) = - \frac{1}{4e}(\frac{e-1}{e})
$$
What am I missing?


$|x|<1\implies \int_{-1}^1 \mathrm dx$

As @SineoftheTime points out $|x|\le 1$ means $-1\le x \le 1$. And, btw, 1) your evaluation of the $y$ integral in your comment is wrong, and 2) polar coordinates should not have been an immediate (albeit probably possible) choice  here to do the double integral, as the limit for $r$ depends on $\theta$ (say). Nonetheless! You should probably visit your instructor and have him/her go over setting up the limits with polar coordinates for this problem... You will need to understand what's happening here to do other problems where more complicated polar coordinates (say) is required.

Thank you for pointing this out. The correct evaluation of the y integral should be $-1/e$. Thanks.

@TerribleStudent no!!!! for one thing the integrand is positive, so the integral can't be negative. Secondly the indefinite integral $\int e^{-y^2}, dy$ has no 'closed form' answer, e.g. with '$u$-substitution,' which you seem to be using...

The reason your calculations are off:

The area $D$ that is given in the problem is clearly a square of the side, say $a$, equal to $a=2$ with its center at the origin and the sides parallel to the $x$ and $y$ axes respectively. When you perform a transform to polar coordinates, you should express the new boundaries in terms of your transformation: namely, the initial square should remain the same in that new polar parametrisation of your coordinates. However, from what we see in your calculation, you claim the polar angle to change from $0$ to $\frac{\pi}{2}$ which clearly only covers the upper-right side of the square. Hence, the integrals in the initial and transformed coordinates are not the same.
What you could have done:

The simplest way to deal with the integral would be to stay in the Cartesian coordinates and use the fact that your variables are independent. That is, you may integrate over $x$ independently of integrating over $y$. Let's proceed to that:
$$
I=\int_{-1}^{1} \, x e^{-{x^2}}  \, dx \int_{-1}^{1} \, e^{-{y^2}}  \, dy = -\frac{1}{2} \int_{-1}^{1} \, e^{-{y^2}}  \, dy \int_{-1}^{1} \, e^{-{x^2}}  \, d(-{x^2}) = \\
-\frac{1}{2}  \int_{-1}^{1} \, e^{-{y^2}}  \, dy \cdot e^{-{x^2}} \Bigg|_{-1}^{1} = -\frac{1}{2} \int_{-1}^{1} \, e^{-{y^2}}  \, dy \cdot (e^{{1}^2} - e^{{(-1)}^2}) = -\frac{1}{2} \int_{-1}^{1} \, e^{-{y^2}}  \, dy \cdot 0 = 0
$$

Thank you. Why did you put $d(-x^2)$ in the integral?

To make it clearer that the following substitution would be $t=-x^2$. But that is a common technique anyway, read this for more.
